# Matching text from 2 files

Tags: c

I have written a program that is designed to recover linux system passwords by searching for matching hashes which are present in two text files

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000
//Declaring Functions to match word in file
int matchfile(char *shadowfilename, char*hashtablefilename);
//shadowfilename for shadow.txt hashtablefilename for hash table
void UsageInfo(char *shadowfile, char * hashtablefile );
//Display usage info on arguments for program
void UsageInfo(char *shadowfile, char * hashtablefile) {
printf("Usage: %s %s <shadowfile> <hashtable>\n", shadowfile,hashtablefile);

}

//main function.
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int result, errcode;
    //Display format for user to enter arguments and
    //End program if user does not enter exactly 3 arguments
    if(argc < 3 || argc > 3) {
        UsageInfo(argv[1],argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }


    system("cls");
//Pass command line arguments into searchstringinfile
    result = matchfile(argv[1], argv[2]);

//Display error message
    if(result == -1) {
        perror("Error");
        printf("Error number = %d\n", errcode);
        exit(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
//Declaring Functions to match word in file
//int matchfile(char *shadowfilename, char *hashtablefilename);
//shadowfilename for shadow.txt hashtablefilename for hash table

int matchfile(char *shadowfilename, char *hashtablefilename){

    FILE *shadowfile;
    FILE *hashtable;
    char strshadow[MAXCHAR];
    char strhash[MAXCHAR];


    shadowfile = fopen(shadowfilename, "r");
    if (shadowfile == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",shadowfilename);
        return 1;
    }


    hashtable = fopen(hashtablefilename, "r");
    if (hashtable == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",hashtablefilename);
        return 1;
    }

    //Getting text from the 2 files
    while (fgets(strshadow, MAXCHAR, shadowfile) != NULL &&fgets(strhash,MAXCHAR, 
    hashtable) != NULL){
    printf("%s", strshadow);
    printf("%s", strhash);
    int linenumber = 1;
    int search_result = 0;
            //Matching words line-by-line

    if((strstr(strshadow,strhash)) != NULL) {
        //Display line in which matched word is found
        printf("A match found on line: %d\n", linenumber);
        printf("\n%s\n", strhash);
        search_result++;
    }
    linenumber++;
}


fclose(shadowfile);
return 0;

}
```

However, I am unable to match the two hash values present in the two files due to the characters in front of them.

hashtable.txt.
This file contains the missing password in plain-text and is corresponding hash values.
The format is as follows: (password):(hash)

```
banana:$1$$Tnq7a6/C1wwyKyt0V/.BP/:17482:0:99999:7:::
```

shadow.txt. This file contains the account username in plain-text and is corresponding hash values.
The format is as follows: (user):(hash)

```
pyc1:$1$$Tnq7a6/C1wwyKyt0V/.BP/:17482:0:99999:7:::
```

As seen above, the words 'banana' and 'pyc1' prevent the program from detecting the two hashes from being detected.
Could someone tell me the changes I need to make to overcome this ?
Thank you.
Edit:Clarified format of shadow.txt and hashtable.txt

Comment: So you know the first few letters cause the identity check to fail. What keeps you from comparing only from the first ":" ?

Comment: Hello ! It's nice to see you again ! Could you guide me on what I can do to avoid this ?

Comment: Solution is simple: learn more C. What needs to be done is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to skip characters in string until some condition is met is:

```
char someString[MAXCHAR];

for (char* ptr = someString; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++) {
    if (conditionIsMet(ptr)) {
        doSomething();
        break;
    }
}
```

In your case, `conditionIsMet(ptr)` should be comparing `*ptr` to `':'` and in that case, the password hash is under `(ptr + 1)` (string starting from the next character). I think you can write the rest of the code yourself.